# My pc cannot boot past grub [Kali Linux]

Tags: boot, kali-linux, hardware

I have Kali Linux installed on my hp envy as the primary Os. No dual boot. I had issues with the bios and got it replaced and reprogrammed. My PC now boots past bios, into grub. It even gives me a Kali Linux selection from the grub. My PC cannot boot into Kali after that. It gives me this error.

[image: Error showing on my screen]

`[    2.393708] mce : [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 4: ba00000000060403`

`[    2.393842] mce : [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff9b922e45> {intel_idle+0x85/0x130}`

`[    2.393977] mce : [Hardware Error]: TSC 162c5d0a12 MISC 1e3c`

`[    2.394103] mce : [Hardware Error] PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1420096831 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode cc`

My pc boots fine when I run Kali Linux on a live CD on fail safe mode but crashes when I run windows from a USB hard drive.

Comment: Kari should not be used as a primary OS, or by beginners. It is a specialist OS for penetration testing. Most (probably all) of the tools that is provides are available in other Gnu/Linux distributions.

Comment: You are using (trying to) Gnu/Linux. Linux is its kernel, not the whole system. Linux is often (mistakenly) used to refer to the whole system, including on this site. The tag linux-kernel is for question about the kernel, so I removed it.

Comment: If you can post the entire error message as text, then someone may be able to feed it through `mcelog --ascii` for you. I assume that this will decode some of the codes.

Comment: I have been using it as a primary OS for close to 2 years now.

Comment: It takes all sorts.

Comment: Why should I not use Kali Linux as my primary OS?

Comment: Kali is good at what it is good at, but Kali was not designed for this purpose, and is a pain. There are many better choices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97028/discussion-between-david-kariuki-and-ctrl-alt-delor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is here:

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check: Processor context corrupt
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal machine check
```

A machine check is a signal directly from the CPU itself that a serious error has been detected. Unfortunately, the most common reasons for machine checks are various kinds of hardware faults. It might be:

- simple CPU overheating (clogged air vents? heat sink not properly attached to CPU?)
- RAM failure (run a memory tester overnight if possible)
- data corruption on system bus (usually requires motherboard replacement, which may or may not be cost-effective on a laptop = warranty replacement of the complete computer might be in order)
- something else (this list is not exhaustive)

Your first goal should be to get any irreplaceable data backed up somewhere outside the laptop. If you don't already have external backups, you might need to do something like removing the SATA HDD/SSD or the M.2 SSD module from the laptop, plugging it to an appropriate external enclosure and copying your data out of the drive that way. If you feel you're out of your depth here, get a professional involved.

The second goal is getting the hardware fault diagnosed and fixed. If the system has detachable RAM memory modules, and there is more than one of them, you might try running with just one module installed. Try each module at a time: if one works and the other fails, you'll know which one of the modules is bad. If there is just one memory module, you'll need to get a second compatible module for testing. If the memory modules are not user-replaceable in that laptop model, that kind of testing will obviously be impossible.

At this point, you will have done essentially everything a skilled amateur can be expected to do with a problem like this one.

Even if the system is still under warranty, the sad reality is that you'll probably first have to prove the problem also exists when using a supported OS, i.e. Windows. But that error looks severe and repeatable enough that it will probably also crash the Windows installer, so be sure to try that, so that you will be able to honestly say you tried. It will probably be proof enough to get the warranty replacement process started.

Comment: My memory and hard drive tests passed without any problem.

Comment: My PC boots fine when I run Kali Linux on a live CD on fail safe mode but crashes when I run windows from a USB hard drive. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because your hardware is messed up. There's no real test for mobo hardware failures. There are tests, but none are reliable in the way disk or memory check tools are. The reason probably for safe mode not crashing is it's not using much of the OS, unlike Windows. Less intense use may not be triggering the hardware failure.

Comment: OK, Thank you for help.